# “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift2

I just did the last Xcode update (8.3), and I have the message :

**“Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.**

Knowing that the "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" option has just been removed from the build settings, how can I generate my app in Swift 2.3 without doing any conversion for now ?

Comment: You read the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW160), didn't you? – **Deprecation and Removal Notices** Xcode 8.3 no longer supports Swift 2.3.

Comment: I get this now, using Swift 3 and Xcode 8. Huh?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the navigator selection bar, click the magnifying glass, then search for "`SWIFT_VERSION`" You will find the places in the project where you can adjust the swift version accordingly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would be the best solution.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. XCode 8.2 was the last version to support Swift 2.3. You have to either update to Swift 3 or use Xcode 8.2.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to download the old version. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 7):

In My case 
I selected Pod and changed swift version for specific pod. This works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To programmatically change swift version of pods, you may add this inside your Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['Alamofire','OtherPod','AnotherPod'].include? target.name
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

In Swift 4, if you are using objective-c as well,

you may turn on @objc inference so the swift project will run properly on objective-c.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['Alamofire','OtherPod','AnotherPod'].include? target.name
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_SWIFT3_OBJC_INFERENCE'] = 'On'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot as XCode 8.2 was the last version to support Swift 2.3. You will have to either update your code to Swift 3 or use Xcode 8.2.

Answer (score 2):

Damn you Xcode, now I have to migrate to Swift 3.0. It clearly shows up this alert on opening or building an old project with Swift 2.3 so I suggest lets migrate :( :(

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change the Swift Language Version to supported version in Build settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Updated, It works for me:

**Step 1:**
Go to your ios folder and open podfile and do below simple changes;

*first change:*

```
target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks! # <--- add this single line
      # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
      # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
      system('rm -rf .symlinks')
      system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
```

*second changes:*

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2' # <--- add this single line
    end
  end
end
```

**Step 2:**
Open your current working project from Xcode i.e. Go to ios folder and open yourProjectName.xcworkspace file;

```
Add an empty Swift file to your Flutter iOS project in Xcode and accept to add bridging header.
```

**Step 3:**
 Open Terminal and again install using below command;

```
pod install
```

If project already open then close it and open again i.e  yourProjectName.xcworkspace file , clean and build.