# Unsupported swift version (SWIFT 5)

Tags: swift, xcode

before you mark this question as a duplicate, I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366024/how-to-fix-swift-version-3-0-is-unsupported-supported-versions-are-4-0-4-2)

and it didn't work for me.

how to fix this error:

```
error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'DropDown')
```

Comment: First Update Xcode after that Change language version Target->build setting -> Swift compiler language -> select 5, 4.2 etc. it will Work.

Comment: I have many reasons, not to update Xcode to the new version, anyway I found an alternative solution, I updated my Podfile to downgrade the 'DropDown' Library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For XCode 10.1, select your Pods File

[image: Select Pod]

-> Go to Build Settings -> Choose your Pod -> Search "Swift" -> Navigate to "Swift Language version" -> Set to desired language version.

[image]

Comment: What if his pod was updated to contain Swift 5 code?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri If pod is supporting prior language then it will help. Otherwise, Logically there are two options either find another pod or update your Xcode :D.

Comment: Exactly. So you agree that your answer will not work for him. :)

Comment: how do you know, that which pod he is using has supported only swift 5. You must check the pod first. Particularly only, in this case, it will not work. I found a similar problem while using SwiftyJson in Xcode 10.1. I resolved it.

Comment: i know because he says that in the question.

Comment: I think u must check this line in question as well

"supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'DropDown')"

Comment: That line is not relevant. His pod contains code in Swift 5. What do you think Xcode that doesn't know Swift 5 will do?

Answer (score 7):

You have code which was compiled on the new Xcode 10.2 or the beta version which supports Swift 5. Update your Xcode to the latest version.

Comment: I have many reasons, not to update Xcode to the new version, anyway I found an alternative solution, I updated my Podfile to downgrade the 'DropDown' Library.

Comment: @MhmdRizk you are not supposed to have any. It is fine if you do not update to the beta versions, but definitely not recommended for the stable builds.

Comment: I work in many projects at the same time, and right now I don’t have the time to update the build settings for each project, but as soon as I have time to, I will.

Comment: @MhmdRizk You can do it, without updating your xcode.

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary no he can't unless he downgrades his pod version.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri In his case, he can.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Xcode 10.2 release make sure you reboot MacOS. I had the exact same problem and reboot helped.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answer, I added this to my podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5.0'
      end
  end
end
```